# combining numbers from multiple text files using bash

Tags: bash, jenkins, awk

I'm strugling to combine some data from my txt files generated in my jenkins job.

on each of the files there is 1 line, this is how each file look:

```
testsuite name="mytest" cars="201" users="0" bus="0" bike="0" time="116.103016"
```

What I manage to do for now is to extract the numbers for each txt file:

```
awk '/<testsuite name=/{print $3, $4, $5, $6}' my-output*.txt
```

Result are :

```
cars="193" users="2" bus="0" bike="0"
cars="23" users="2" bus="10" bike="7"
cars="124" users="2" bus="5" bike="0"
cars="124" users="2" bus="0" bike="123"
```

now I have a random number of files like this:

```
my-output1.txt
my-output2.txt
my-output7.txt
my-output*.txt
```

I would like to create single command just like the one I did above and to sum all of the files to have the following echo result:

```
cars=544 users=32 bus=12 bike=44
```

is there a way to do that? with a single line of command?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please post sample lines of your files in your question that will give us clear picture, thank you.

Comment: i already added how the file looks:
on each file there is 1 line. look in the question. thank you! @RavinderSingh13

Comment: You have posted output of your `awk` command, if you can post input of sample files then we will get better picture of it and can write it in single `awk` command.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i edited the question with how the files look. all of them look the same just different numbers

Comment: Since you open all those files in awk already, why don't you calculate the running sum inside your `awk` program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way to do so a bit long:

```
awk '/<testsuite name=/{print $3, $4, $5, $6}' my-output*.xml | sed -e 's/[^0-9]/ /g' -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/ *$//g' | tr -s ' ' | awk '{bus+=$1;users+=$2;cars+=$3;bike+=$4 }END{print "bus=" bus " users="users " cars=" cars " bike=" bike}'
```

M. Nejat Aydin answer was good fit:

```
awk -F '[ "=]+' '/testsuite name=/{ cars+=$5; users+=$7; buses+=$9; bikes+=$11 } END{ print "cars="cars, "users="users, "buses="buses, "bikes="bikes }' my-output*.xml
```

Comment: You don't need `sed`. A single `awk` command would do the job: `awk -F '[ "=]+' '/testsuite name=/{ cars+=$5; users+=$7; buses+=$9; bikes+=$11 } END{ print "cars="cars, "users="users, "buses="buses, "bikes="bikes }' my-output*.xml`

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `awk` code, using `match` function in here. Since `awk` could read multiple files within a single program itself and your files have `.txt` format you can pass as `.txt` format to `awk` program itself.

Written and tested in GNU `awk` with its `match` function's capturing group capability to create/store values into an array to be used later on in program.

```bash
awk -v s1="\"" '
match($0,/[[:space:]]+(cars)="([^"]*)" (users)="([^"]*)" (bus)="([^"]*)" (bike)="([^"]*)"/,tempArr){
   temp=""
   for(i=2;i<=8;i+=2){
     temp=tempArr[i-1]
     values[i]+=tempArr[i]
     indexes[i-1]=temp
   }
}
END{
   for(i in values){
     val=(val?val OFS:"") (indexes[i-1]"=" s1 values[i] s1)
   }
   print val
}
' *.txt
```

***Explanation:***

- In start of GNU `awk` program creating variable named `s1` to be set to `"` to be used later in the program.
- Using `match` function in main program of `awk`.
- Mentioning regex `[[:space:]]+(cars)="([^"]*)" (users)="([^"]*)" (bus)="([^"]*)" (bike)="([^"]*)"`(explained at last of this post) which is creating 8 groups to be used later on.
- Then once condition is matched running a for loop which runs only even numbers in it(to get required values only).
- Creating array values with index of i and keep adding its own value + tempArr values to it, where tempArr is created by match function.
- Similarly creating indexes array to store only key values in it.
- Then in `END` block of this program traversing through values array and printing the values from indexes and values array as per requirement.

***Explanation of regex:***

```
[[:space:]]+       ##Matching spaces 1 or more occurrences here.
(cars)="([^"]*)"   ##Matching cars=" till next occurrence of " here.
 (users)="([^"]*)" ##Matching spaces followed by users=" till next occurrence of " here.
 (bus)="([^"]*)"   ##Matching spaces followed by bus=" till next occurrence of " here.
 (bike)="([^"]*)"  ##Matching spaces followed by bike=" till next occurrence of " here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In GNU `awk` only with using `RT` and `RS` variables power here. This will make sure the sequence of the values also in output should be same in which order they have come in input.

```
awk -v s1="\"" -v RS='[[:space:]][^=]*="[^"]*"' '
RT{
  gsub(/^ +|"/,"",RT)
  num=split(RT,arr,"=")
  if(arr[1]!="time" && arr[1]!="name"){
    if(!(arr[1] in values)){
      indexes[++count]=arr[1]
    }
    values[arr[1]]+=arr[2]
  }
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
     val=(val?val OFS:"") (indexes[i]"=" s1 values[indexes[i]] s1)
  }
  print val
}
' *.txt
```

Comment: didnt work, result was:
cars="193" users="2" bus="0" bike="0"
cars="23" users="2" bus="10" bike="7"
cars="124" users="2" bus="5" bike="0"
cars="124" users="2" bus="0" bike="123"

i'm looking to combine it to 1 line.

Comment: @DevFromI, k sure, its updated now, please check my updated code now. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Pass all .txt files to this program and we are Good to go then.

Comment: @DevFromI, Added 1 more solution, both solutions use GNU `awk` as mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
$ cat script.awk
BEGIN {
    FS="[= ]"
} {
    gsub(/"/,"")
    for (i=1;i<NF;i++) 
      if ($i=="cars") cars+=$(i+1)
        else if($i=="users") users+=$(i+1);
          else if($i=="bus") bus+=$(i+1); 
            else if ($i=="bike")bike+=$(i+1)
} END {
print "cars="cars,"users="users,"bus="bus,"bike="bike
}
```

To run the script, you can use;

```
$ awk -f script.awk my-output*.txt
```

Or, as a ugly one liner.

```
$ awk -F"[= ]" '{gsub(/"/,"");for (i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i=="cars") cars+=$(i+1); else if($i=="users") users+=$(i+1); else if($i=="bus") bus+=$(i+1); else if ($i=="bike")bike+=$(i+1)}END{print"cars="cars,"users="users,"bus="bus,"bike="bike}' my-output*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if (split($i, a, /=/) == 2) {
         gsub(/"/, "", a[2])
         sums[a[1]] +=a[2]
      }
}
END {
   for (i in sums) print i "=" sums[i]
}' file*

bus=15
cars=464
users=8
bike=130
```